# bookstore, ordering of books

Tags: combinatorics

A bookstore has 3 copies of the calculus book, 4 copies of the algebra book, and 5 copies of the statistics book.  How many different orders can they be arranged on a shelf?

My thinking:
12 books, so 12!

Comment: Are all the 12 books distinct, though? By your logic, AABB is the same as AABB, but they will count as different if you arrange all the letters separately.

Comment: it would be 12! iff all books were distinct . It so happens that is not the case. You would have to divide by $n!$ for each repeat where $n$ is the number of books repeated for one kind(calculus, algebra, statistics)

Comment: the 12 books are not distinct, 3 calc, 4 algebra, 5 statistics

Comment: Exactly. That's why you cannot conclude your answer to be $12!$ . See the answers below for an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start with a simpler example. Say we have the letters A,A,B. We need to find the total number of ways in which they can be arranged.

If we say "there are 3 letters so the total number should be $3!$", we are having repetitions such as `AAB, AAB` because we assumed that they were all distinct when they weren't. As you can see, a total of $2!$ arrangements are repeated *among the $A$s alone*, so we need to get rid of those by diving by $2!$, so we end up with $$\frac{3!}{2!}$$

Similarly, here we have 3 copies of one book, 4 copies of one, and 5 copies of one. We get rid of them by dividing for each of those, so we end up with $$\frac{12!}{3!\times 4!\times 5!}$$

Answer (score -1):

Since the question mentions *copies* of the book, I will assume that copies are identical to each other. In this case, the number of ways is given by 
$$N = \frac{12!}{3!\times4!\times5!}$$

Comment: You can add this link to your answer to make it more clear why you have divided by those factorials:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets